# Category Blog - Layout if the intro image is set

Tags: layout, category-blog

I would like to add a tag around the intro text, but only if the article has an intro image.

It's easy to add markup around the image in the intro_image layout file.  And in the file blog_item.php, I can see where the text is included:

```
<?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
```

But can anyone help me write an if statement so that I can add a `<div>` around the text so that I can control the layout if the intro image has been set?

Comment: Sorry, that bit of php doesn't show up right in the post - I don't know how to add it correctly but I hope you know what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the intro image that's used in intro_image layout, use the same check as in the layout:

```
<?php $images = json_decode($this->item->images); ?>
<?php if (!empty($images->image_intro)) : ?>
    <div><?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?></div>
<?php else : ?>
    <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: No, I want to put a div around the text, but ONLY if there is an image.  If there's no intro image, no div around the text.  Basically, I want a column effect if there is an image.

Comment: Yes, that's what this snippet does. Replace <?php echo $this->item->introtext; ?> line with it.

Comment: Many apologies, I mis-read it.  It works perfectly!  Thank you so much.